# How to disable the checkout option in azure pipelines? I wanted it to checkout just once

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, checkout, azure-pipelines-yaml

My azure pipeline consists of multiple stages. Each stage has one job. Usually, when I run a pipeline it's checking out from the repo for each stage. But I don't want it to be check-out for every stage. Is there any option for disabling it?

Answer (score 0):

You know what each job is actually a seprate machine, and this is a mainly reason why it is dowloaded each time. If you don't want to check out it you need to add `- checkout: none` for each step. However, deployment job doesn't checkout code automatically.

Comment: Does that mean if I want to "install dependencies, download required files and build code", I should do all these in same job?

Comment: Yes and in this way prepare package for later deployments.